# Need to reduce HTML in Angularjs using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Having some HTML

```
 <tr class="matrix_row" ng-repeat="process in matrixCtrl.processes | filter : { park: parentIndex } track by $index">
    <td class="properties" ng-click="dashboardCtrl.currParam=0; dashboardCtrl.currentProcess=process">{{process[1]}}</td>
    <td class="properties" ng-click="dashboardCtrl.currParam=1; dashboardCtrl.currentProcess=process">{{process[2]}}</td>
    <td class="properties" ng-click="dashboardCtrl.currParam=2; dashboardCtrl.currentProcess=process">{{process[3]}}</td>
    <td class="properties" ng-click="dashboardCtrl.currParam=3; dashboardCtrl.currentProcess=process">{{process[4]}}</td>
    <td class="properties" ng-click="dashboardCtrl.currParam=4; dashboardCtrl.currentProcess=process">{{process[5]}}</td>
    <td class="properties" ng-click="dashboardCtrl.currParam=5; dashboardCtrl.currentProcess=process">{{process[6]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Didn't find what I need in documentation. I need to make something like:

```
 <tr class="matrix_row" ng-repeat="process in matrixCtrl.processes | filter : { park: parentIndex } track by $index">
    <td class="properties" ng-repeat="key(1,2,3,4,5,6) in process" ng-click="dashboardCtrl.currParam=key; dashboardCtrl.currentProcess=process">{{process[key]}}</td>

</tr>
```

The problem is that objects have more properties than 1-6. Object looks like

```
 { 
  1:"one",
  2: "two", 
  3: "three", 
  4: "four",
  5:"five",
  6:"six", 
  time: "15:14", 
  mail:"somemail@mail.com"
 }
```

I need to display numeric properties. Is there any way to do this without

```
<td ng-repeat="key in process" ng-if="!isNaN(key)">
```

?

Comment: `key in [1,2,3,4,5,6]`…?

Comment: @deceze it is not an array, it are objects. And there are more properties than 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Yes, but that number seems to be the only variable in those lines…?

Comment: @deceze can't understand what do you mean exactly. Object looks like `{1:"one",2: "two", 3: "three",4: "four",5:"five",6:"six", "time": "15:14", "mail":"somemail@mail.com"}`

Comment: @deceze I need to display only numerical properties, but is there any way then `<td ng-if="!isNaN(key)">`?

Comment: Update your question to include all these additional clarifications!

Comment: @deceze Done, thank u!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In can be done by pre-filtering inner `ng-repeat` variable

Let the controller be

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = { 
  6:"six",
  1:"one",
  2: "two", 
  3: "three", 
  4: "four",
  5:"five",
  time: "15:14", 
  mail:"somemail@mail.com"
 }

 $scope.filtNum=function(process){
   var result = {};
    angular.forEach(process, function(value, key) {
        if(!isNaN(+key) && angular.isNumber(+key)){
          result[key] = value;
        }
    });
    return result;
 }
});
```

Here the inner ng-repeat is mentioned as per the requirement

```
   <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in filtNum(data)">{{value}}</div>
      </body>
```

Working plunker link [Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/EzSp7FhGymsedZBwXmjk?p=preview)